What is the best order of doing exercise for the same muscles - in order of increasing difficulty or decreasing?
I have been doing crunches for years, so I can do a lot of them in each set. So I added some variants
I am labelling the basic crunch with leg position as /\__ as Crunch 1 - have been doing this for years. Then I added 3 extra sets of Crunch 2, where I do crunches with leg position like below
\
 \__
Then added 3 more sets where I keep 1 leg & 1 arm alternately raised while doing crunches - Crunch 3
So Crunch 3 tires my stomach the fastest, 2 next & basic crunch (Crunch 1) takes the longest time to tire my stomach - So I can do much more repetitions of Crunch 1 than Crunch 2 or 3
I am trying to figure out a few things

What order should I do it in? Should I first do the hardest crunch - 3 sets of Crunch 3 & then 3 of Crunch 2 & then 1. Or the opposite order? Pros and Cons of either order? i.e. one option may be better for getting more muscular the other may be better for losing fat - if so I want to know which option helps what?

Or should I not do 3 different types of crunches at all & just do 9 sets of Crunch 3 which the hardest - pros & cons of either option?


Note: I don't want to add any machine or weights to the routine because I visit the gym only around 60-80 days a year & remaining time, I do only floor exercises at home without any machine or weights.

nitpick: I'm hoping when you do crunches you're tiring your ab muscles, not your stomach...

@Luciano - I am not sure I understand the difference! Would you elaborate?

Anatomy: stomach is the main digestive organ inside your abdominal cavity; what you are training with crunches are actually the abdominal muscles, on the outside. Feeling the abs sore after training is fine, but not your stomach!

Between different kind of crunches there's not much to worry about. Do whatever feels best.
The guiding principles in exercise order are to put high-skill and explosive/max-effort/max-speed movements first. More complex movements should go earlier than simpler exercises but this is not a hard rule below a certain threshold that doesn't seem like is a concern here.
Next come strength and other higher-intensity exercises. Then muscular-endurance work (like crunches), complex cardio-conditioning (e.g. circuit workouts), and last would be slow repetitive cardio like jogging. This is the ideal general shape of a workout and is not set in stone.
Exercise order matters primarily in 1. doing first what is most important to you, and 2. making sure movements which develop skill or demand careful coordination or maximum effort come before exercises which can be pushed through less mindfully.
